# Optimistic Concurrency using Stored Procedures in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the entity framework, using stored procedures, I would like to perform an update on my table using optimistic concurrency. I've been unable to get this working, without modifying my existing update stored procedure. I'm trying to determine if there is a way I can map my existing stored procedure so that a concurrency exception will occur when no rows are updated.

Some background information:

- I've mapped the update stored procedure (including the timestamp) column in my .edmx file
- My existing stored procedure looks like the following (the actual table names and columns are obviously omitted):

  ```
  UPDATE Table SET Column = @Column1, Column2 = @Column2 ....
  WHERE PK = @PK AND Timestamp = @Timestamp

  SELECT PK, Column1, Column2, ....., Timestamp
  FROM Table WHERE PK = @PK
  ```
- In the event that the update fails (due to a timestamp mismatch) the select portion of the stored procedure *will* still return a row.

When I modify the stored procedure to the following:

```
   UPDATE Table SET Column = @Column1, Column2 = @Column2 ....
   WHERE PK = @PK AND Timestamp = @Timestamp

   IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       SELECT PK, Column1, Column2, ....., Timestamp
       FROM Table WHERE PK = @PK
```

Then everything works as expected, and the concurrency error occurs.

Alternatively if I make the stored procedure return an output parameter, and map that output parameter to the "Rows Affected Parameter" in the Entity Framework's .edmx file, then the concurrency error also works as expected.

This solution (i.e. using the output parameter) is explained best, I found, here:
http://petermannerhult.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/entity-framework-4-with-optimistic-concurrency-and-stored-procedures/

Neither of the above steps seem like they should be necessary though, as I would assume that the Entity Framework could just use the number of rows updated to determine if it should raise a concurrency exception. I've used these exact same stored procedures (with optimistic concurrency) in ADO.NET DataSets, without any problem. So my question is how can I use my existing stored procedures, without modification, to enable optimistic concurrency in the Entity Framework?

Comment: I don't think its a problem with EF. EF do not have access to the row counts of your update statements within your stored proc. So you have to handle that check yourself by checking rowcount within your proc or by returning the rowcount from the proc so EF can figure out if the row was updated.

Comment: @Satish Thanks for the response, but could you explain why the EF does not have access to the row counts of my update statement? This information should be available when executing a stored procedure in SQL Server. For example it can be accessed using the RecordsAffected property of an SqlDataReader (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected.aspx). Given that this exact stored procedure works in ADO.NET (with optimistic concurrency) it must be possible to determine the number of rows updated. Is there a reason the EF cannot do this?

Comment: When you have a stored proc the caller of the proc doesn't know the rowcounts of each of the statements within your proc. If you were to call the same proc using ADO.NET I'd think it would behave the same way as EF did.

Comment: @Satish I don't think it's true that the caller of the proc doesn't know the rowcounts of each statement within the proc. As illustrated by the documentation for the property RecordsAffected, the caller of the stored procedure can in fact access the number of rows that were modified by the stored procedure (for each result set). This does work in ADO.NET, and I presume it works by looking at the RecordsAffected property to determine if it's == 1.

Comment: It appears that EF just doesn't get a `RecordsAffected` property back from a Stored Procedure excution on its own.  I could speculate on all kinds of reasons why that might be, but ultimately only the EF product developers can say for sure.  And it doesn't really matter why, it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yea, unfortunately I think you are probably correct. This is the conclusion I've come to as well. It seems that modifying my stored procedures is the only way to make this work :-(

Comment: Agreed.  And since `OUTPUT` parameters can also be optional stored procedure parameters, you should be able to add it without having to change any other calling code.

Answer (score 0):

In the Stored Procedure Mapping window of the EDMX designer, there are two check boxes next to each property.  `Use Original Value` and `Rows Affected Parameter`.  As you noted, the `Rows Affected Parameter` requires you to use an output parameter in the proc.  However, if you select `Use Original Value` for the timestamp, it compares them and throws an `OptimisticConcurrencyException` if the two don't match.  This should allow you to get the exception without having to modify the procedure.

Answer (score -1):

If you really don't want to change the stored procedure code, you can compare the Timestamp returned from the stored procedure to the Timestamp passed into it. If different then you have a concurrency error.